# Is array concatenation with + and concat different

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, concatenation

> In [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xameeramir/6euozd0w/), When using `+` operator the delimeter `,` is skipped, while `concat` method is not skipping `,`.

In javascript, generally the concatenation with `+` operator and `concat` method is same. Doesn't it apply to arrays as well?

Comment: There is no `+` operator in JS defined to accept arrays. So - no `+` and `Array.prototype.concat` produce completely different results.

Comment: `var usingPlus = alpha + ',' + numeric;` will add comma too.. Are you expecting to get comma on its own ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider this:

```
[1, 2, 3] + [4, 5, 6] // "1,2,34,5,6"
[1, 2, 3].concat([4, 5, 6]) // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Using the plus concatenation operator on array will make the arrays undergo the following steps:

```
[1, 2, 3] + [4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3].toString() + [4, 5, 6].toString()
"1,2,3" + "4,5,6"
"1,2,34,5,6"
```

Comment: is the behaviour because of number data type of arrays?

Comment: @student all arrays behave the same irregardless of their contents.

Comment: @student: No, it's because `+` isn't defined for arrays, and so both operands are converted to strings.

Answer (score 3):

When using `+`(**String concatenation**) operator on array, the array is implicitly type-casted to string by calling [`toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString) method on Array prototype.

To concat two **arrays**, use [`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) method.

Which one to use depends on the use case.

1. To get the result as **string**, you can use `+` operator
2. To get the result as **array** use `concat`.

```js
function testing() {
    var alpha = ["a", "b", "c"];
    var numeric = [1, 2, 3];
    var usingPlus = alpha + numeric;
    console.log(typeof usingPlus);

    var usingConcat = alpha.concat(numeric);
    console.log(typeof usingConcat);
};

window.onload = testing;
```

Answer (score 2):

The plus operator is defined to solve two purpose:

1. To add the numbers.
2. To join the strings.

But it is not defined to be applied on arrays. From the [ECMA section](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_Section_11.htm#Section_11.6.1)

> #### 11.6.1   The Addition operator ( + )
>
> The addition operator either performs string concatenation or numeric addition. The production `AdditiveExpression : AdditiveExpression + MultiplicativeExpression` is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let `lref` be the result of evaluating `AdditiveExpression`.
> 2. Let `lval` be `GetValue(lref)`.
> 3. Let `rref` be the result of evaluating `MultiplicativeExpression`.
> 4. Let `rval` be `GetValue(rref)`.
> 5. Let `lprim` be `ToPrimitive(lval)`.
> 6. Let `rprim` be `ToPrimitive(rval)`.
> 7. If `Type(lprim)` is `String` or `Type(rprim)` is `String`, then
>
>    1. Return the String that is the result of concatenating `ToString(lprim)` followed by `ToString(rprim)`
> 8. Return the result of applying the addition operation to `ToNumber(lprim)` and `ToNumber(rprim)`. See the Note below 11.6.3.